# I have a Canon model LBP6230dn. I would like to know how many pages I have printed using this printer.

Tags: xorg

I have a Canon model LBP6230dn. I would like to know how many pages I have printed using this printer. I'm using Windows 7. I have connected to this printer through network

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get this information natively.

The printer may have a web admin console (browse to http://) to check which might give you the total for the printer as a whole, but I doubt it has "Per User" Information.

Also, your PC won't store this info as the print record is purged once the spooler has sent it onto the printer.

Its probably worth investing in some form of print management software (PCounter or an open source equivilent) if you need to track this information.

This type of software acts as an intermediary or secondary.

If it is an intermediary, it has all the jobs sent to it instead of direct to the printer.  It can capture details of the print job, log it and then send the job onto the printer on your behalf.

If it is a seconday software, it will capture and send data from the spooler service and doesn't actually act as a "man in the middle"

Answer (score 0):

If the printer is connected via its own network interface, then it will almost certainly have a built-in web page. Somewhere on there, it will tell you the page count.

Start your browser and type the printer's IP address in the address field (not into the Google search box!). The printer's page will come up. If the page count is not visible, go through the various tabs and buttons and you should find it.

This cannot be done via USB. If the printer is USB connected,then you can still plug the printer into your router (both interfaces can be connected simultaneously). Your router or DHCP server will give the printer an IP address. Check the router or print a configuration page to find out what that address is. Then use your browser as above.